# Go reflect.MakeFunc. How to return a err=nil as reflect.Value?

Tags: go, reflection

How to return a err=nil as reflect.Value? I need to write a swap function to use with reflect.MakeFunc().

```
//my swap implementation, that call the original function and cache results
func swapFunc(ins []reflect.Value) []reflect.Value {
    //After cache the first return (Offer) of function FindBestOffer(int)(Offer,bool,error),
    //i need to return the best Offer cached and default values 
    //for the two other returns (bool=true, err=nil)

    outs := make([]reflect.Value, 3) //mock cache return

    outs[0] = reflect.ValueOf(Offer{10, "cached offer", 20})
    outs[1] = reflect.ValueOf(true)
    outs[2] = reflect.ValueOf(nil).Elem() // --> Doesn't work!

    return outs
}
```

[Go Playground full example](http://play.golang.org/p/inQ7Z9tR3N)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's tricky, you have to use [`reflect.Zero`](http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Zero):

```
out[2] = reflect.Zero(reflect.TypeOf((*error)(nil)).Elem())
```

[<kbd>play</kbd>](http://play.golang.org/p/DhrZU6BOWN)

Answer (score 2):

Defining a typed nil error works too...

```
var err error = nil
outs[2] = reflect.ValueOf(&err).Elem()
```

Just out of curiosity.
[Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/RgKImlXMOe)